# R - How do I remove a varying number of digits from a date-vector

Tags: r, bigdata, data, data-cleaning

I want to remove a varying number of digits from a date vector. My date vectors looks like this:
[image]

I want to convert this vector into a date vector, but first I have to get rid of the number in front of it. This is where I struggle since this number can be (here from 88-106) varys in my data.frame from 1-50 000. Does anyone know how to remove these number without destroying the date? I tried the following, but it didn't work out:
[image]

I would really appreciate your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assuming your strings are of the form [NUMBER][WHITESPACE][STUFF-TO-KEEP]

you can use regex, for example with the stringr package.

```
# construct strings
strings <- paste(c(1,11,111,1111), "KEEP")
strings
[1] "1 KEEP"    "11 KEEP"   "111 KEEP"  "1111 KEEP"

stringr::str_remove(strings, "[0-9].* (?=[a-zA-Z])")
[1] "KEEP" "KEEP" "KEEP" "KEEP"
```

the regex "[0-9].* (?=[a-zA-Z])" expained:

```
'[0-9].* ' # (including the whitespace!) 
# matches any number of digigs from 0 to 9 followed by a whitespace

(?=[a-zA-Z]) 
# this is a lookahead group, so an additional requirement is,
# that a match is only used when the above match is followed
# by a letter in the alphabet, small(a-z) or large (A-Z)
```

of course, str_remove removes the matches string.